# iFrame suppress authentication popup for https when parent window is already authenticated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iframe

I've developed a print mechanism for an intranet application running over HTTPS. Using javascript and jQuery I create an iframe in the page and populate it with all the dynamic data that should be printed.

The iframe has a source of `/MyController/Print` which just returns a blank dummy page. This is then replaced with the dynamic content. I do this to avoid having the page location be "about:blank" on the print outs and to get a popup about some secure content, some insecure content.

This works great locally, but once it's on the https server I get a domain authentication popup when trying to create the iframe. It's asking for my username and password (even though the main application never does --- it uses the internal network to identify users).

Is there some way to suppress the user/pass popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iframe in this kind of situation usually creates x domain security issues.

This issues are happening according to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Therefore the recommended workaround for this matter would be for you to use

```
<style media="print">
   css properties to modify the page for print
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks... that's what I was trying to avoid. My other option is to define the src as "javascript:false;" and that works. I was just hoping to use a friendlier URL in the printout. Any other ideas?

Comment: While this technically doesn't answer the question, I'm gonna go with "there is no definite answer on this". Furthermore, your response kind of inspired me to code the printing functionality a different way which did include a CSS for print. So even though I couldn't get it working 100% exactly like I wanted, this was good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is actually from another post but i really like the solution.

you can set your action controller to compose your printable data as pdf

```
public FileStreamResult Print(int id)


{
     var model = _CustomRepository.Get(id);
     this.ConvertToPDF = true;
     return View( "HtmlView" );
 }

 public override OnResultExecuting( ResultExecutingContext context )
 {
      if (this.ConvertToPDF)
      {
          this.PDFStream = new MemoryStream();
          context.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new PDFStreamFilter( this.PDFStream );
      }
 }

 public override OnResultExecuted( ResultExecutedContext context )
 {
      if (this.ConvertToPDF)
      {
          context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
          this.PDFStream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
          Stream byteStream = _PrintService.PrintToPDF( this.PDFStream );
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( byteStream );
          context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader( "content-dispostion",
                 "attachemnt; filename=report.pdf" );
          context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader( "content-type",
                 "application/pdf" );
          context.HttpContext.Response.Write( reader.ReadToEnd() );
      }
}
```

I am assuming you are using .net mvc. I hope im not wrong

Comment: This is really cool. While it's not applicable for what I'm doing now, I may come back to this in the future. Thanks!